# Does sleep schedule affect circadian rhythm?

Tags: sleep, psychology, temperature, circadian-rhythms, homeostasis

During the circadian rhythm, the internal human body temperature supposedly peaks around 4-6 pm. Let us assume that the average person goes to bed around 11 pm and sleeps for 8 hours. In that case would someone whose sleep schedule is offset by +2 hours — i.e, goes to bed at 1 am but still sleeps for 8 hours — have an equally offset peak body temp, i.e. at 6-8 pm?